# SQL Server : substring from specific position of '-' hyphen

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to perform a substring operation in SQL Server and get a string from start of hyphen character (-).

My input string is :

```
'44345434595-E535-12349-5273-202003-16785'
```

and I want to extract the string from 4th instance of hyphen to 5th instance of hyphen and my desired result is : `202003`

Comment: Just to update - the string is not of any fixed length.

Comment: Look up CharIndex and PatIndex

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string_split` function in `sqlserver`

```
declare @str varchar(max)= '44345434595-E535-12349-5273-202003-16785'

select * from (select value, row_number() over (order by charindex('-' + value + '-', '-' + @str + '-')) rn
    from string_split(@str, '-')) t1
where t1.rn in (5)
```

Since there's no guarantee of `ordering` using `string_split` function, we need to sort by `position` based on your `-`

```
row_number() over (order by charindex('-' + value + '-', '-' + @str + '-'))
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` does not maintain any order, so in general your answer might not work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, that is why there is row_number() -> order by

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ . . . This doesn't work if components are repeated in the string.

Answer (score 1):

If your input string has fixed format you can set position and lenght directly

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(yourColumn, 29, 5) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the string is not of any fixed length, so I would not be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If the Format is Fixed You can use Substring for that:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @STR='44345434595-E535-12349-5273-202003-16785'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@STR, 29, 6)
```

Output: `202003`

Comment: Didn't @Leonid already give this answer 10 minutes before you posted?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I Haven't Seen his answer

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that might suit your requirement and will work if the input has exactly 5 hypen.

```
DECLARE @data varchar(50)= '44345434595-E535-12349-5273-202003-16785'
select 
reverse(
 SUBSTRING
 (
  SUBSTRING
  (
   reverse(@data),
   charindex('-',reverse(@data),1)+1,
   len(@data)
  ),
  1,
  charindex('-',SUBSTRING(reverse(@data),
  charindex('-',reverse(@data),1)+1,
 len(@data)))-1)
);
```